I trying to add new s3 event notification resource and get an error
I trying to create s3 event notification for SQS in Terraform
so I navigate the terraform registry and copy there's code as a start, then I changed naming convention little bit and run
everything were create beside the event notification.
can someone know to tell me what wrong here?
this is my module tf file:
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "create-applicant-policy" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "*"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    actions   = ["sqs:SendMessage"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:sqs:*:*:s3-event-notification-queue"]

    condition {
      test     = "ArnEquals"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = [aws_s3_bucket.vardo-assets-bucket.arn]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "vardo-assets-bucket" {
  bucket = var.assets-bucket
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "create-applicant-queue" {
  name   = var.create-applicant-queue
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.create-applicant-policy.json
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "vardo-assets-bucket-event-notification" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.vardo-assets-bucket.id

  queue {
    queue_arn     = aws_sqs_queue.create-applicant-queue.arn
    events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:Put"]
    filter_prefix = "Prospects/"
    filter_suffix = ".pdf"
  }
}

and that the error I getting:

Error: creating S3 Bucket (vardo-assets-dev) Notification: operation error S3: PutBucketNotificationConfiguration, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: P23KKT6S8M2T1RZG, HostID: AJhzSoWnHWR/TvUDvoCeDWS3Idb83EhQIDt7QsNhqA90bWu/GXwjnXMJ/s/ty3kGsWQInKbOYvwtee5Z3fhYwg==, api error InvalidArgument: Unable to validate the following destination configurations with module.create-applicant-module.aws_s3_bucket_notification.vardo-assets-bucket-event-notification, on modules/createApplicant/main.tf line 30, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "vardo-assets-bucket-event-notification": 30: resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "vardo-assets-bucket-event-notification" {


Try reducing your code... according to the documentation filter_prefix and  filter_suffix are Optional try removing those also in the examples they use events        = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"] try that too, the idea is to isolate the problem

I solved it, prefix was not right hah, tnx alot!
